# What tools does Flask or MySQLAlchemy provide for selecting a specific user's information in a database?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Stack: Flask, SQLAlchemy, Python

I'm teaching myself these languages by building a simple spa reservation app.

I use Flask's current_user object to capture the currently logged in user, so intuitively I think I would somehow use this to query their specific information in my database. But I'm not sure how.

Currently I have it set up to just retrieve all the data in two tables.

views.py:

```
@views.route('/view-reservations', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def view_reservations():
    return render_template('view-reservations.html', user=current_user.username, spa_query=SpaReservation.query.all(), hotel_query=HotelReservation.query.all())
```

view-reservations.html:

```
    {% for reservation in hotel_query %}
        {{reservation.check_in}}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for reservation in spa_query %}
        {{reservation.spa_start}}
    {% endfor %}
```

How can I target just the logged in User's information? My foreign key that links a user to these two tables is the User's "cust_id" property by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to used `filter` or `filter_by` methods

```
@views.route('/view-reservations', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def view_reservations():
    return render_template(
        'view-reservations.html', 
        user=current_user.username, 
        spa_query=SpaReservation.query.filter_by(cust_id=current_user.id).all(), 
        hotel_query=HotelReservation.query.filter_by(cust_id=current_user.id).all()
    )
```